# Lookup column header based on max value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a case where there are multiple values corresponding to an id. I need to get the value having highest value and also the heading of the value column.

For Example:

```
id    a   b   c   d   e   f   g
12    6   0   7   0   1   0   0
14    0   1   0   0   2   4   0
16    5   0   0   9   0   0   2
18    0   2   5   0   0   1   3
```

Expected Result:

```
id    a   b   c   d   e   f   g  max   col
12    6   0   7   0   1   0   0    7     c
14    0   1   0   0   2   4   0    4     f
16    5   0   0   9   0   0   2    9     d
18    0   2   5   0   0   1   3    5     c
```

I can get the 'max' column by using the max() fn. But how can i obtain the values for 'col' which gives me the heading corresponding to the max value in the table?

Please help!

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

To find the Max:

```
=MAX(B2:H2)
```

to find the column:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(I2,2:2,0))
```

Put these in there corresponding columns in row 2 and copy down.

[image]

Comment: just a tad too slow

Comment: what if there are two identical values in the row?

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed then unless you have Office 365 Excel you would need vba to put the answer in one cell.  If in two or more cells it would take an array formula.  But that is not what the OP asked and therefor I did not provide.